# Solving the PDE $\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = -v \frac{\partial n}{\partial \alpha} - \mu n $ using a given ansatz

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology, mathematical-biology

I'm working on exercise 25 of Chapter 10 in *Mathematical Models in Biology* by Edelstein-Keshet. In the exercise we analyze the following chemotherapy model which accounts for the process of cell aging/maturation:

$$ \hspace{2cm} \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = - v \frac{\partial n}{\partial \alpha} - \mu n \hspace{2cm} (*)$$

The variables and parameters are as follows:

- $\alpha \in [0,1]$ denotes the maturity of a cell ($0 = $ brand new cell, $1 = $ fully mature cell)
- $t$ denotes time
- $n(\alpha,t) = $ the age/maturity distribution of malignant cells at time $t$
- $v = $ the maturation rate of malignant cells (a positive constant)
- $\mu(t) = $ the malignant cell death rate at time $t$, and is given by
  $$ \mu(t) = \frac{K_1(t) c(t)}{K_2(t) + c(t)} $$

for some functions $K_1, K_2, c$ (which are not given). In part (b) of the exercise we are told to assume a solution of the form
$$n(\alpha,t) = N_0 e^{\beta t} h(\alpha) e^{-A(t)}$$

and asked to show that
$$ A(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \mu(\tau) \, d\tau.  $$

(We are not told what the function $h$ is; I'm assuming that it can be determined in the same manner as $A$.) I have made progress on finding $A(t)$, but I'm having trouble finishing it. Here's my work so far:

Differentiating the ansatz gives:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial n}{\partial t} &= N_0 h(\alpha) e^{\beta t - A(t)} \cdot (\beta - A'(t)) = n(\alpha,t) (\beta - A'(t)) \\[5pt]
  \frac{\partial n}{\partial \alpha} &= N_0 h'(\alpha) e^{\beta t - A(t)} = \frac{h'(\alpha)}{h(\alpha)} n(\alpha,t),
\end{align*}

where the last equality is assuming that $h$ is nonzero. Then we have
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial n}{\partial t}(\alpha,t) + v \frac{\partial n}{\partial \alpha}(\alpha,t) + \mu(t) n(\alpha,t) = n(\alpha,t) \left[\beta - A'(t) + v \frac{h'(\alpha)}{h(\alpha)} + \mu(t) \right].  
\end{align*}

Thus, assuming that $n \not\equiv 0$, our ansatz solves $(*)$ iff
\begin{align*}
   \beta - A'(t) + v \frac{h'(\alpha)}{h(\alpha)} + \mu(t) \equiv 0.
\end{align*}

Rearranging this equation gives

\begin{align*}
   A'(t) - \mu(t) = \beta + v \frac{h'(\alpha)}{h(\alpha)}. 
\end{align*}

Now since the LHS depends only on $t$ and the RHS depends only on $\alpha$, we must have
\begin{align*}
   A' - \mu \equiv C \equiv \beta + v \frac{h'}{h}
\end{align*}

for some constant $C$. In particular, $A'(t) = \mu(t) + C$, and so
\begin{align*}
     A(t) = A(0) + \int_{0}^{t} \mu(\tau) \,d\tau + Ct. 
\end{align*}

Now if I can show that $A(0) = C = 0$ then I'll be done. This is the part where I'm stuck....We are given the boundary condition $n(0,t) = 2 n(1,t)$, but it's not clear if this is helpful...Any ideas for how to proceed?

Comment: You can absorb $A(0)$ and $C$ in other constants in your Ansatz, which is also the reason you cannot prove that they are zero.

Comment: @Hetebrij: Thanks for your comment. So are you saying that $A(t) = A(0) + \int_{0}^{t} \mu(\tau) \,d\tau + Ct$ is in fact the correct expression for $A(t)$, where $A(0)$ and $C$ are arbitrary constants?  Regarding the "absorbing" of constants, I think I kind of see what you mean: We can write the solution as $n(\alpha,t) = (N_0 e^{-A(0)}) e^{(\beta - C)t} h(\alpha) \exp\left( -\int_{0}^{t} \mu(\tau) \,d\tau \right)= \tilde{N}_0 e^{\tilde{\beta} t} h(\alpha) \exp\left( -\int_{0}^{t} \mu(\tau) \,d\tau \right)$, where $\tilde{N}_0 := N_0 e^{-A(0)}$ and $\tilde{\beta} := \beta - C$...

Comment: The absorbing of $A(0)$ into the $N_0$ feels natural, since any constant multiple of a solution of the PDE is again a solution (because the PDE is linear). But something about the $e^{-Ct}$ term feels odd. If $n(\alpha,t) = N_0 e^{\beta t} h(\alpha) \exp\left( -\int_{0}^{t} \mu(\tau) \,d\tau \right)$ solves the PDE, it's not immediately clear to me why $N_0 e^{(\beta - C)t} h(\alpha) \exp\left( -\int_{0}^{t} \mu(\tau) \,d\tau \right)$ should also be a solution.

Comment: You have an Ansatz, where $\beta$ is an unknown constant, which will be restricted by the initial conditions. So in your Ansatz, it does not matter if you took $\beta$ or $\bar{\beta}$. However if you took $\bar{\beta}$ in your Ansatz, then $A(t)$ looks a lot nicer, and $h(\alpha)$ will also look a bit nicer :). You might want to put your comments as answer to the question btw.

Comment: @JJacquelin, I believe you solved the PDE $\partial_tn=-v\partial_{\alpha}n-\color{red}{\mu}$. The general solution to the PDE $\partial_tn=-v\partial_{\alpha}n-\color{blue}{\mu n}$ is
$$
n(\alpha,t)=\exp\left(-\int \mu(t)dt\right)F(\alpha-vt).
$$

Comment: @Gonçalo . You are right. I delate my comment.